# GWT to get value from date field

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

I am using GWT ext and trying to get the values from page and setting it in pojo class.

Except date field all the values are obtained using

(TimeField) ComponentMgr.getComponent(id[2])).getText())....

But while using the same snippet for date field it fails to perform.

Can any one help me with this issue please......

Comment: Am I not clear with my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

dateField.getText();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a string to a date field, you'll have to parse it. Bear in mind that there are already out-of-the-box date pickers in GWT 1.6. If you're using a version that does not come with date pickers, there are several projects [like](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-datepicker/) [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/).

Answer (score 0):

I have also used date field many times.
DateField field = new DateField();
field.getValue();

This will return value as Date instance.So If your pojo has date property then you need to parse it.
For the string value you should go for getText() method.